Why is たってよ used in this sentence to denote a request?
いいじゃん　ちょっとくらい。遊んでくれたってよ.
The character says this to is friend who has been avoiding him for a long while... There are no more words after this.
I seem to read it "It's fine, just for a bit this much. Please hang out with me at least this much" but why would a sentence finish with たってよ if it's a request?


いいじゃん　ちょっとくらい　遊んでくれたってよ

That's an example of colloquial 倒置(inversion/anastrophe). To rewrite it in a normal word order:

ちょっとくらい　遊んでくれたって　いいじゃんよ

≈ ちょっとくらい　遊んでくれたって　いいじゃないか
≈ ちょっとくらい　遊んでくれても　いいだろう
"You can hang out with me a little, right?"
"It wouldn't hurt to hang out a little, would it?"
～たっていい means almost the same thing as ～てもいい, literally "It's okay even if..." → "It's alright to do..." "can do..." (～たって might sound a bit more casual/colloquial than ～ても.)
The よ is a 間投助詞(interjectory particle).

細かいですが、倒置を直したあと、「よ」がどこかに行ってしまってるので、厳密に言うと「いいじゃんよ」が正しいんじゃないかと思います…

@bro! ああ確かになるほどね・・・ broでタグ付けすんの好きやわ～
